# IE9 does not show question count with new activity

Tags: support, internet-explorer-9, newest-questions

I searched for the `C#` keyword on SO and it starts to show the newest activity indicator on top for both Firefox and chrome as below:

[image]

However, IE9 does not show the newest activity indicator.

Comment: What you see [in this page](http://websocketstest.com/)? (When visiting it with your IE9)

Comment: No web sockets, just like @MadScientist explained

Comment: Yep. No bug, at least not on SE side. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IE9 does not support web sockets](http://caniuse.com/websockets) which are used for this feature. As this is an entirely optional feature for SE, there is no fallback for older browsers that don't implement web sockets.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'll accept your answer when I'm allowed to :)